# (gcloud.dataproc.batches.submit.spark) unrecognized arguments: --subnetwork=

Tags: apache-spark, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to submit google dataproc batch job. As per documentation [Batch Job](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/quickstarts/spark-batch#dataproc_serverless_create_batch_workload-gcloud), we can pass `subnetwork` as parameter. But when use, it give me

> ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.batches.submit.spark) unrecognized arguments:
> --subnetwork=

Here is gcloud command I have used,

```sh
gcloud dataproc batches submit spark \
    --region=us-east4 \
    --jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar \
    --class=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
     --subnetwork="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/us-east4/subnetworks/network-svc" \
    -- 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [dataproc batches docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/batches/submit), the subnetwork URI needs to be specified using argument `--subnet`.

Try:

```sh
gcloud dataproc batches submit spark \
    --region=us-east4 \
    --jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar \
    --class=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --subnet="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/us-east4/subnetworks/network-svc" \
    -- 1000
```